# How Can I Reference an Array in a C# Using Statements

Tags: c#, arrays, using

In C++ I can do:
`using String3 = std::array<char, 3>`

If I wanted to do the same in C#, how would I go about doing so with a `using` statement?

For instance, the following does not work: `using String3 = char[3]`.

I want to alias an array of 3 characters.

The end goal is to, in my program, cast an array of bytes into the proper type, so I need contiguous memory.

Comment: in c++ arrays are fixed in size at compile time. in .net they are fixed at runtime.

Comment: You can use `using` in C# to alias a type, but not a specific instance.

Comment: This seems like an XY probelem. Don't cast a byte array into other type. Are you dealing with p/invoke? Take a look at `Marshal`. Marshalling an struct and taking care of alignment is better,

Comment: @LouisGo Marshalling I'd what I need. But how can I Marshal a user defined struct that isn't made up entirely of primitives? For instance a strict Foo that has an field Bar of type XYZ?

Comment: @TeeZadAwk Marshaling a user defined struct shall not be done. I might get your question wrong, so more information would help understanding your real question. Edit your question, and elaborate on your use case. Explain what you want to do but failed. Also you  might want to change your question title.

Comment: @LouisGo This is what I am referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60715619/how-can-i-marshal-a-user-defined-struct-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the array, something like this:

```
class String3
{
   private List<char> _array;
   public IEnumerable<char> Array => _array;
   public String3(char a, char b, char c)
   {
      _array.Add(a);
      _array.Add(b);
      _array.Add(c);
   }
}
```

Then could pass around `String3` whereever it is required.

Comment: I added a note to my post: "The end goal is to, in my program, cast an array of bytes into the proper type, so I need contiguous memory."

I don't think a byte[] will reinterpret_cast very well into a String3 (I implemented my own reinterpret_cast). I'll need to think of something else.

Comment: The my suggestion would be to treat the memory block as a stream, and provide a 'stream cracker' to extract the stream into it's real components.   You have to remember, C# is not C or C++, especially regarding memory layouts.  One could argue that doing what you are doing in C++ is not that great, and won't work on all platforms.